# React displaying icon based on props value

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a vacation project with React (TS), NodeJS, mySQL and trying to do save and like icons with material UI based on the props (if props === true or props >=1).
The icons are in the - div className="MenuContent".
How to make a function to check the value of the props?
Tried few ways and didn't work (errors).
This is my Card component:

```
import VacationModel from "../../../Models/VacationModel";
import appConfig from "../../../Utils/Config";
import "./VacationCard.scss";
import BookmarkIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Bookmark';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import TurnedInNotIcon from '@mui/icons-material/TurnedInNot';

 interface VacationCardProps {
vacation: VacationModel;
}

 function VacationCard(props: VacationCardProps): JSX.Element {

return (
    <div className="VacationCard">
        <div className="Card">
            <div className="Wrapper" style={{ backgroundImage: 
`url(${appConfig.vacationImagesUrl + props.vacation.imageName})` }}>
                <div className="Header">
                    <div className="Date">
                        <p className="checkIn">Check In: {props.vacation.checkIn}</p>
                        <p className="checkOut">Check Out: {props.vacation.checkOut}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="MenuContent">
                        <ul>
                            <li><TurnedInNotIcon fontSize="small" /></li>
                            <li><FavoriteBorderIcon fontSize="small" /><span> 
  {props.vacation.followersCount}</span> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="Data">
                    <div className="Content">
                        <h1 className="Title">
                            {props.vacation.destination}
                        </h1>
                        <p className="Text">
                            Description: {props.vacation.description}
                            <br />
                            Price: {props.vacation.price}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 );
}

export default VacationCard;
```

Thanks!

Comment: *How to make a function to check the value of the props?* What **exactly** do you mean by that? Looking at your props it can only have one prop `vacation`. Do you want to show / hide a Icon based on some value in the `vacation` object? If so you could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I want to show a specific icon if the vacation.props.followrs === 0 and another one if its greater or equal to 1.
I will try the ternary operator but I think I already tried and failed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you want to show a specific icon if the props.vacation.followersCount === 0 and another one if its greater or equal to 1.
You can try this:

```
{vacation.props.followrs > 0 ? "show Your icon that you want for greater or equal to 1" : "show other icon }
```